# Can't browse svn repo using TortoiseSVN on Windows Server 2008

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2008

Environment is:
Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
Slik-Subversion-1.6.11-x64
TortoiseSVN-1.6.8.19260-x64-svn-1.6.11

I have setted up svn srvice based on [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html) guidlines and can connect work with host via svn command lines like `svn list svn://localhost`, but TortoiseSVN can't connect to it even on server machine itself. All firewall types are off. TortoiseSVN error message is: 
Can't connect to host 'localhost': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance,

UPDATE: tried [this solution](http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn/browse_thread/thread/9e31eeff7850b9b2) but didn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure this is "programming related"...

Comment: but SO is full of svn related issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself but have not found the solution yet. TortoiseSVN in Windows 2008 uses ipv6. And conflict between ipv6 and ipv4 is root cause of problem.

BTW slik svn works good in command line. And in TortoiseSVN I'm using file protocol instead (something like file:///F:/myfolder).

Comment: If you're using the file:// protocol, the network protocols shouldn't be involved.

Answer (score 1):

I blogged about [getting TortoiseSVN to work with SlikSVN](http://www.renaissance-design.net/code/installing-and-configuring-svnserve-and-tortoisesvn-on-windows/) recently, including the IP fix.

Comment: tnks. I will use your solution next time I encounter the problem,

Answer (score 0):

The root directory served up by svnserve isn't the root of your repository.

Instead of `svn list svn://localhost`, try `svn list svn://localhost/reponame`

(Where reponame is, of course, the name of your repository)

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar problems myself but maybe my conditions differ.
I noticed I could access the repository through the browser as my repo was setup to be accessed form the outside.
We also have to make use of a proxy inside the company.
So, at SVN settings, I added the proxy.
The moment I tried to do repo browser, it went through without hanging and asked to accept the certificate (permanently), entered svn credentials and... voila!

Maybe this can help someone.
Cheers!